# A Href Link doesn't work after resizing window (chrome / azure)

Tags: html, django, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, azure

My hyperlinks don't work, after I resize the browser window.

Here is what I did:

I've an image with an hyperlink attached. For styling the link is nested in an div-element:

```
<div class="row">
{% for n in search_results %}
<div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 voffset-15px">
     <a href="{{ n.url }}" target="_blank">
           {% autoescape off %}{{ n.get_image }}{% endautoescape %}
     </a>

     [here are some buttons with java scripts attached who are in front of the image]

 </div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

The page is created by django and hosted on azure. I use bootstrap for styling, so depending on the size of the device there will be either 3 or 6 elements in one row.

Here the problem:

If I use the development server from django, it works all perfect. Links work with any window size.

On the webserver, it is displayed allright, but the links work only, if the window is full size. If I resize the window to half screen, the links stop working...

I'm using chrome.

Thanks a lot for your help!